# Apache dbcp exception in recursion

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jndi, connection-pooling

I'm getting error like:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 8,374,094 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 8,374,094 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3364)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at com.mycode.MyLoginDAO.validateUser(MycodeDAO.java:517)
    at com.mycode.MyLoginFB.validate(MycodeFB.java:85)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ValidateActionForm.validate(ValidateActionForm.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractValidateActionForm.execute(AbstractValidateActionForm.java:120)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3345)
    ... 35 more
```

when I used below code for long time or sending request to server n No.of times.

I Configured my application with Apache dbcp on My-sql using below context.xml

context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MYDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="12345" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/egDB" 
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="1000"/>
```

From this DBConnection Singleton class returning connection to all calling methods in their classes and .jsp files

DBConnection class:

```
package my.code;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DBConnection implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1565029633902701330L;
    private static DBConnection dbConnection;
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private Connection connObj;
    private Context initContext;

    private DBConnection() {

    }

    public static Connection getDBConnection() {
        if (dbConnection == null) {
            dbConnection = new DBConnection();
        }

        Connection connectionObj = dbConnection.getConnection(dbConnection
                .getDataSource());
        try {
            while (connectionObj == null || connectionObj.isClosed())
                connectionObj = dbConnection.getConnection(dbConnection
                        .getDataSource());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return connectionObj;
    }

    private Connection getConnection(DataSource ds) {
        try {
            connObj = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connObj;
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            try {
                initContext = dbConnection.getContext();
                Context envContext = (Context) initContext
                        .lookup("java:/comp/env");
                dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/NichehireDB");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        if (initContext == null) {
            try {
                initContext = new InitialContext();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return initContext;
    }
}
```

Using Connection in DAO/DTO classes or jsp files:

```
package my.code;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MycodeDAO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7146087855230830066L;

    private String jobTitle;
    private String jobDesc;



    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public String getJobDesc() {
        return jobDesc;
    }

    public MycodeDAO() {

    }

    public MycodeDAO(String jobTitle, String jobDesc) {

        super();
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.jobDesc = jobDesc;

    }

    public Vector<MycodeDAO> getSavedJobs(String js_email_id) {

        Vector<MycodeDAO> savedJobsVector = new Vector<MycodeDAO>();

        Connection connObj = DBConnection.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstmtObj = null;
        ResultSet rsObj = null;
        PreparedStatement appliedPstmtObj = null;
        ResultSet appliedRSObj = null;

        try {
            pstmtObj = connObj
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "select * from jobs where jobid = ?",
                            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            pstmtObj.setInt(1, 102);
            rsObj = pstmtObj.executeQuery();

            while (rsObj.next()) {

                jobTitle = rsObj.getString("jobTitle");
                jobDesc = rsObj.getString("jobShortDesc");



                savedJobsVector.add(new MycodeDAO(jobTitle, jobDesc));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (connObj != null) {
                try {
                    if (!connObj.isClosed()) {
                        connObj.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.gc();
        }
        System.out.println("savedjobVector size:\t" + savedJobsVector.size());

        return savedJobsVector;
    }
}
```

Like above I had so many dao,dto and jsp classes. In different classes its raising the error.
When I refresh the .jsp pages which contains dao/dto code, server going down saying 5xx error and when I look into log file its saying Max active sql connections are used.

Please let me know where I went wrong. Please do the needful to resolve this exception.
Note: MySQL max connections: 350

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your mysql server is closing your idle connections in pool.

You could check [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) in your my.ini.

I noticed you have enabled the *removeAbandoned* flag you your datasource, but looking at [DBCP docs](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) you can read

> If you have enabled "removeAbandoned" then it is possible that a connection is reclaimed by the pool because it is considered to be abandoned. This mechanism is triggered when (getNumIdle() < 2) and (getNumActive() > getMaxActive() - 3)

...so if you never reach 98 active connections and less than 2 idle connections the *removedAbandoned* mechanism is never triggered, and the mysql connection could timeout.